# Material UI TextInput Label Overlaps Input Border

Tags: reactjs, input, material-ui, label, uitextfield

Using a basic

```
<TextField 
  key={givenName.name}
  name={givenName.name}
  value={givenName.value}
  error={!!givenNameError}
  helperText={givenNameError}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  variant={'outlined'}
  label={<Trans>Given Name</Trans>}
  required
  fullWidth={true}
  disabled={isProcessing}
/>
```

from `Material UI` and the labels see to have a fixed "opening" when it shrinks.  Using a `outlined` box and the label length is much less than half the width of the input.  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What is `<Trans>`?

Comment: <Trans> is a lingui library. But has no effect as I have tried with and without. 

I did find a solution to this from Google themselves as this is a known issue. Just overwrite the CSS for the label. Background Color and a little paddingRight.